# TreeMap Java. Как устроена

Tags: java, treemap

Меня интересует как работает `TreeMap` в `Java` под капотом. Нигде не смог найти подробного описания того как эта карта устроена изнутри, везде просто говорится что она использует красно-черные деревья, то есть она сортирует по ключам. Но тут у меня возникает вопрос -  ведь значения в деревьях хранятся отсортированы по своим правилам и это не совсем напоминает ту сортировку которую мы привыкли видеть. На [картинке](https://hsto.org/web/ae2/9ed/b02/ae29edb02c724c209d25ec3ee48724f5.png) мы видим дерево - порядок цифр соответсвует правилам хранения в деревьях, но как на выходе из мапы вылетают отсортированные объекты? Я понимаю что преимущества хранения в деревьях это быстрый поиск объекта.
Но я не понимаю как сама карта возвращает все объекты отсортированные именно так как мы привыкли (1,3,7,10.....) хотя в дереве они расположены будут не совсем так. Пробовал рассматривать сорцы но пока не смог разобраться... То есть я хочу узнать как происходит выборка из дерева и на выходе получаются отсортированные объекты по ключу.

Comment: Красно-черное дерево - частный случай бинарного дерева поиска. Его основное свойство гласит: в левом поддереве вершины с весом V все вершины имеют вес меньше V, а в правом - больше (или больше-равно). Таким образом, поиск элемента работает, как обычный бинарный поиск в отсортированном списке с тем лишь отличием, что у нас не список, а специальное дерево. О бинарных деревьях можно прочитать много где, достаточно погуглить.

Comment: [Balanced Search Trees](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/33balanced/)

Comment: наверное вы не поняли мой вопрос. Я понимаю как балансируются и как находятся объекты в дереве. Но я не понимаю как они выбираются из дерева именно в том порядке который нас интересует(определенный Comparator или Comparable). По какому пути(алгоритму) проходит через дерево итератор например? С левой ветки? но мне вот тут и не понятно.

Comment: То есть я понимаю как найти и выбрать конкретный элемент, но не понимаю как выбрать все в порядке возрастания)

Comment: in-order обход выберет все в порядке возрастания. Comparator будет учитываться при добавлении элементов, а уже имеющиеся в дереве элементы по сути уже сортированы.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! это именно то что я хотел узнать (когда я читал про деревья, информации о том как их обходить не нашел, а когда пытался найти ее, то видимо не правильно создавал запрос в поисковике).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще, самый тупой алгоритм вида "найти минимальный элемент и удалить его, пока в дереве есть элементы" отработает за NlogN, так что можно так и сделать.

Можно конечно и за N, примерно так:

```
ArrayList<int> result = new ArrayList<int>();
BinaryTreeSearch tree; // произвольное бинарное дерево

void inOrder(Node v)
{
    if (v.left)
        inOrder(v.left);
    result.add(v);
    if (v.right)
        inOrder(v.right);   
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    inOrder(tree.root);
}
```

Извиняюсь за код - хотел показать только алгоритм, плюс на джаве я не писака, а макака, так что получилось, как получилось.

Почему обход верный: по свойству, в левом поддереве все элементы меньше данного, так что сначала нужно добавить все из них, а в правом все элементы больше данного, так что их добавить нужно в конце.

Comment: имхо, если уж писать ответ на такой вопрос, то писать основательно. Пояснить, что такое бинарное дерево. Потом что такое бинарное дерево поиска. Потом что такое Сбалансированное бинарное дерево поиска. И после уже говорить про время работы такого дерева на какие то операции. А так ваш ответ, хоть он и верный, то выгглядит как просто что то выдернутое из контекста.

Comment: @tym32167 автор вопроса написал выше, что понимает, как устроено бинарное дерево поиска и балансирование, так что не вижу смысла расписывать это.

Comment: 1) Если бы автор действительно понимал это, вопроса бы не было 2) ваш ответ будет читать множество людей, он предназнчен не только для автора. Впрочем, я только совет даю, делать что то или не делать решать только вам.